# Removing non-economic factors from the regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, econometrics

I have the following:

I was asked prepare a quick equation that would be used to roughly calibrate forecast of defaults in economy that we subscribe to, to our company's defaults.

Initially I regressed our historical defaults on historical default rates in local economy. Yet, they would surely not have a proportional relationship, due to the firm's growth and customer base changing drastically past 2 years (company was started 4 years ago).

Is there any clever to train the model to **exclude** firm-specific effect in such calibration (ie isolate economic-driven impact and not volatile company's past), other than adding some fix effect variables?

Much appreciated !

Comment: This is a bit counterintuitive while we would like to see both company specific variation and economic condition simultaneously.  Maybe a mixed-effects modelling is more suited then just excluding firm-specific models.

Comment: @MehmetSuzen it is more a form of calibration so in the future the resulting equation could be applied on the actual economic predictions prepared by professional academic sources (for example apply that equation on 2022 predictions that economists made). I am not that fond of this technique, but apparently it is pretty common in Finance hm

Comment: @MehmetSuzen rather than pure prediction*